# While submitting app to iOS App Store, "Unable to unzip application"

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store, submission, application-loader

I've successfully submitted "Product Name" to App Store. However, submitting "Product Name Lite", I keep getting the error "Unable to unzip application" in both Application Loader and built-in Xcode's uploader. Error persists even after eliminating spaces from the product name; in fact, I don't think there's whitespace anywhere in the app or the plist anymore.

What might be causing this "highly descriptive" error?

I'm using Xcode 3.2.5.

---

Attempting to clean, build, and build&archive did not help.

Comment: Try a clean build. In XCode, go to Build->Clean. When it is done, try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your created product does not have any invalid symlinks.

I had a custom "Run Script" build phase which, in full version, created symlinks. In the lite version, some files were deleted, resulting in invalid symlinks. Removing the symlinks allowed the validation phase to succeed, and the app is on its way to Apple's servers.